# Parse Cloud function returns null

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

I need to query on my Installation class so I am forced to use Parse Cloud for it. I'm putting a map as parameter to the cloud function from android and use it for another query but it gives me null:

Here is my cloud function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var query = new Parse.Query("_Installation");
  query.matchesQuery("user", request.params.get("query"))
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      response.success(results.length);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("failed");
    }
  });
});
```

On android:

```
Map<String, ParseQuery> map = new HashMap();
map.put("query", innerQuery);

 ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", map, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(String o, ParseException e) {
                                if(e==null)
                                 Log.d("debug", "cloud function result: " + o);
                                else
                                    Log.d("debug", "cloud function error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        });
```

The code above returns "cloud function result: null".
Btw, I'm not that familiar with javascript.

UPDATE:
When I changed it to `request.params.query`, it gave me this error:

```
Input: {"query":{"where":{"Student_ID":{"$regex":"\\Q13-0699-678\\E"}},"className":"_User"}}
  Failed with: TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toJSON'
    at Object.b.Query.matchesQuery (Parse.js:3:13613)
    at main.js:7:9
```

Answer (score 0):

To pull a variable passed into a ParseCloud function, you would pull it like this:

```
query.matchesQuery("user", request.params.query)
```

Comment: I also tried this and it gives me an error:Object #<Object> has no method 'toJSON'